# Google Cloud Platform SDK with Python

Tags: google-cloud-sdk

Where can I learn google cloud sdk with python? I have already have basic knowledge of python but how to implement gcloud sdk with real world problems?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, Unfortunately this question isnt suitable for StackOverflow, this question seeks for a tutorial instead of asking a specific question which is not suitable at all for Stackoverflow. I recommend you to review the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of stackoverflow for tips on how to ask a good question and what type of questions are [well suited](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the site. Anyways, goodluck on your learning journey and wish you all the best

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question will likely be flagged by others as being "off topic" for Stack overflow.

Before that happens, hopefully I can squeeze in an answer ;-)

Google's documentation for its SDKs is generally excellent: comprehensive and definitive. Sometimes the examples are trivial but, they provide a template.

Rather than proceed from wanting to understand all (each Google [Cloud] service has SDKs in several languages), it may be better to decide what you'd like to do and then build a solution.

Each Google Cloud Platform service e.g. Compute Engine, has documentation that includes so-called [client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/api/libraries) and Python is always included.

One caveat,

For Google Cloud Platform (only) there are at least 2 different types of SDK for every language. The older, more common API Client Libraries and the (Cloud-only!) Cloud Client Libraries. There are also (increasingly?) gRPC-based services for which you can generate an SDK.

See [Client Libraries Explained](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/client-libraries-explained).